# iOS NSDictionary Values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have an array of NSDictionaries and i can access the values in them just fine but i am trying to filter these dictionaries down based on a user's search (user can only search by the dictionary key (@"uniqueSignName").

Once the user has searched through the names property i then need to display ALL dictionary associated data for that @"uniqueSignName" value.

I do the following code and always get the correct amount of NSLogs. For the life of me i cannot remember how to GET those dictionaries.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [filteredDictionaries count]; i++) {
    if ([[[filteredDictionaries valueForKey:@"uniqueSignName"] objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[self.filteredResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {      
        NSLog(@"Power Rangers"); 
    }
}
```

Eg: I search for "John"

> NSLog: @"Power Rangers"

- Correctly only appears once.

Now, how do i access another property of "John's" dictionary?

Comment: Is `filteredDictionaries` an array or a dictionary?  It'd make sense for it to be an array, but you're using it as a dictionary.

Comment: Also I'd break up that long conditional expression by assigning parts of it to local variables - and use the modern Obj-C literal syntax for arrays and dictionaries, instead of `valueForKey:` and `objectForKey:` use `dict[@"key"]` and `array[i]` - it makes things much shorter and easier to read.  Old style Obj-C makes it all too easy to confuse yourself by writing things like this

Comment: Yes sorry, that would have been confusing. filteredDictionaries is an array. Okay I'll shorten it, thanks.

Comment: I think the flow structure is NSDictionary in NSArray? Am I right?

Comment: Yes @Arpit it is an NSArray of NSDictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search the name then better way is that to use NPredicate without iterating the array.

Please see the below example..it may help you...

// Here array is your main array...

```
  NSArray *filteredarray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(uniqueSignName == %@)", @"John"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is solved, I can now access all the filtered properties.

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in filteredDictionaries) {
            if ([[self.filteredResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString: dict[@"uniqueSignName"]]) {
                NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dict[@"pType"]];
                NSLog(@"hugh: %@", myString);
                myString = displayPtype;
            }
        }
```